# Adapting an existing keras model with multiple inputs to tensorflow federated

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to apply federated learning to an existing keras model that takes two inputs. When I call `tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model` and include a dummy batch, I get this error: `ValueError: Layer model_1 expects 2 inputs, but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'packed:0' shape=(2, 20) dtype=int64>]`.

The model accepts two numpy arrays as inputs, so I defined my dummy_batch as:

```
x = tf.constant(np.random.randint(1,100, size=[20]))
collections.OrderedDict([('x', [x, x]), ('y', x)])
```

I dug around a little bit and saw that eventually, `tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor` gets called on the input list (in the `__init__` for `_KerasModel`), and that returns a single tensor of shape (2,20), instead of two separate arrays or tensors. Is there some other way I can represent the list of inputs to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The TFF team just pushed a commit that should contain this bugfix; [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/pull/431/commits/1a87f07eb65962ce300ddfc0f5b96e54468cca24) should be what you want. See in particular the change in `tensorflow_federated/python/learning/model_utils_test.py`--the added test case should have been a repro of your issue, and it now passes.

You were right to call out our call to `tf.convert_to_tensor_or_sparse_tensor`; now we use `tf.nest.map_structure` to map this function call to the leaves of the passed-in data structure. Note that Keras does some extra input normalization as well; we decided not to duplicate that logic here.

This change won't be in the pip package until the next release, but if you build from source, it will be available now.

Thanks for this catch, and pointing to the right place!